# how to make the character jump on slopes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I was following a tutorial on moving on slopes but when coding my character doesn't jump in the correct direction, he always jumps straight and static and doesn't jump parabolic.
Could anyone help me resolve this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;
 
public class Player_Prototipo : MonoBehaviour
{
 
    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float JumpForce;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundMask;
    [SerializeField] private float groundCheckDistance;
    [SerializeField] private float slopeChekDistance;
    [SerializeField] private PhysicsMaterial2D noFrictionMaterial;
    [SerializeField] private PhysicsMaterial2D frictionMaterial;
 
    private Rigidbody2D playerRB;
    private Animator playerAnimator;
    private CapsuleCollider2D playerCollider;
    private SpriteRenderer playerSpriteRenderer;
 
    private float moveInput;
 
    private Vector2 perpendicularSpeed;
    private Vector2 colliderSize;
    private Vector2 position;
    private Vector2 forcedDirection = new Vector2(0,0);
 
    private bool facingRight = true;
    private bool isGrounded;
 
 
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        LoadComponents();
    }
 
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        position = transform.position - new Vector3(0f, colliderSize.y / 2, 0f);
 
        HandleInput();
        HandleAnimations();
    }
 
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MoveAndNormalizeSlopes();
    }
    private void LoadComponents()
    {
        playerRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        playerAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        playerCollider = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider2D>();
        playerSpriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
 
        colliderSize = playerCollider.size;
    }
 
    private void DebugDraw(RaycastHit2D hitSlope)
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(position, Vector3.down * groundCheckDistance, Color.blue);
        Debug.DrawRay(position, forcedDirection, Color.red);
        Debug.DrawRay(position, perpendicularSpeed, Color.red);
        Debug.DrawRay(position, hitSlope.normal, Color.green);
        Debug.DrawRay(position, Vector2.down * slopeChekDistance, Color.white);
    }
 
    private void MoveAndNormalizeSlopes()
    {
        RaycastHit2D hitDirection = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.down, slopeChekDistance, groundMask);
 
        if(hitDirection.collider != null)
        {
            isGrounded = true;
 
            if(isGrounded && moveInput >= 0)
            {
                forcedDirection = new Vector2(hitDirection.normal.y, -hitDirection.normal.x);
 
            }
            else
            {
                forcedDirection = new Vector2(-hitDirection.normal.y, hitDirection.normal.x);
            }
            transform.Translate(forcedDirection * Mathf.Abs(moveInput) * moveSpeed);
        }
        else { isGrounded = false; }
        playerRB.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * moveSpeed, playerRB.velocity.y);
        Debug.Log(isGrounded);
        DebugDraw(hitDirection);
    }
 
    private void HandleInput()
    {
        moveInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded)
        {  
            HandleJump();
        }
        if ((moveInput > 0 && !facingRight) || (moveInput < 0 && facingRight))
        {
            Flip();
 
        }
    }
 
    private void HandleAnimations()
    {
        playerAnimator.SetBool("IsGrounded", isGrounded);
        playerAnimator.SetBool("Walk", Mathf.Abs(moveInput) != 0 && isGrounded);
        playerAnimator.SetBool("Jump", !isGrounded);
    }
    private void HandleJump()
    {
        playerRB.velocity = new Vector2(playerRB.velocity.x * JumpForce, JumpForce);
        //playerRB.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, JumpForce));
    }
    private void Flip()
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        playerSpriteRenderer.flipX = !facingRight;
    }
 
}
```

I've already tried changing the line of code

```
transform.Translate(forcedDirection * Mathf.Abs(moveInput) * moveSpeed);
```

to

```
playerRB.velocity = new Vector2(forcedDirection.x * moveSpeed, playerRB.velocity.y);
```

and that solves the jump, but the character makes small jumps when going down the hill and that's not the behavior I want, I'd like him to stay on the ground when moving on the slopes.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your character angle you will probably want to do something like [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/107827/how-to-make-my-2d-character-stand-normally-on-slope) so that the character doesn't stand on a weird angle.

and regarding the stuttering when moving along the slope you will need to calculate the slope angle and add force upwards as well as forwards based on the angle of the slope(if going up the slope), there is an example of this [here](https://discussions.unity.com/t/any-relatively-simple-way-to-handle-2d-slopes-with-rigidbody2d/151424)